# Notifications about network status changes on iOS

Tags: ios, networking, wifi, reachability

I would like my app to get asynchronous notifications about network status changes, i.e. network goes down entirely or when the phone switches from cellular to Wi-Fi.

I know how to test this synchronously using Reachability, but is there a way to get asynchronous notifications?

Comment: Yes you can, using Reachability. Specifically have a look at the AFNetworking implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Reachability 2.x you can just observe the reachability changed notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:)
                                             name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tiny library, it show up a HUD notification and very easy to use
http://huytd.github.io/datatify/